# How to implement a different permalink structure for custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, permalinks

Tried to use this plugin, but it doesn't seem to be working: https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-permalinks/

I'm setting a permalink structure for by blog posts in settings>permalinks like so: `/blog/%postname%`

I also have a custom post type called "project", where I want the structure to be `/our-work/%postname`, but instead the `/blog` part gets prepended here too. How can I keep a separate permalink structure for this custom post type?

Here's the `register_post_type` function:

```
register_post_type('project', array(
    'public' => true,
    'custom' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'supports' => array('title','editor','revisions'),
    'labels' => array(
        'name' => 'Projects',
        'singular_name' => 'Project',
        'add_new_item' => 'Add New Project',
        'edit_item' => 'Edit Project'
    ),
    'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-portfolio',
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_in_menu' => true,
    'show_in_rest' => true,
    'rewrite' => array(
        'slug' => 'our-work', 
        'with_front' => true
    ),
    'has_archive' => true,
    'show_in_graphql' => true,
    'graphql_single_name' => 'project',
    'graphql_plural_name' => 'projects',
    'cptp_permalink_structure' => '%post_id%'
));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the [`with_front`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/#rewrite) argument to `false`:

```php
register_post_type( 'project', array(
    ... your args.

    'rewrite' => array(
        'slug'       => 'our-work',
        'with_front' => false
    ),

    ... your args.
) );
```